# Apache Drill - Memory / Stream as Data Source

Tags: apache-spark, apache-drill

This may be abusing what the spirit of Drill is meant for, but I was wondering if anyone had tried pointing drill queries at memory or a stream of data.

Maybe:

```
local> select columns[0], avg(columns[5]) from dfs.`tail -f /users/home/carl/incoming.log` group by columns[0], columns[5];
```

Making it more 'Spark'-like?

Comment: This is not supported in Drill.

Comment: I don't think this will work on Spark SQL without using streaming and all.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work in Drill with files. However, Drill 1.12 has added support for Kafka . So you can execute queries on a stream of data in a Kafka topic https://github.com/apache/drill/tree/master/contrib/storage-kafka.